# Empty selector - jQuery Plugin Creation

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, extend

How do you create a plugin that does not require a selector, e.g:

```
$.pluginName();
```

Out of this:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.pluginName = function(options) 
    {
            // options
    };

    // code

})(jQuery);
```

Instead of using this (to prevent other libraries clashing with the `$`):

```
jQuery.pluginName = function(name, value, options) 
{
   // code
};
```

Since if I do this: `$.pluginName()`, Firebug tells me that `$.pluginName()` is not a function unless I add this: `$.('a selector goes here').pluginName();`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place it on the global jQuery instead of the prototype.

```
(function($)
{
//---v----------------namespacing your function in the jQuery namespace
    $.pluginName = function(options) 
    {
            // options
    };

    // code

})(jQuery);
```

Keep in mind that `this` inside your function will not be a jQuery object. It will refer to the global `jQuery` function.

Comment: Good answer, so basically I have to use `$(this)` instead of `this`?

Comment: @lolwut: No, it won't really make sense to do `$(this)` at all because `this` is not a DOM element. It is the jQuery function, and library.

Answer (score 2):

You use

```
(function($)
 {
        $.pluginName = function(options) 
        {
                // options
        };

            // code

})(jQuery);
```

This is an immediately executed anonymous function that takes one argument and is bound to parameter, $, to which a value, jQuery, is supplied.

Comment: Would someone be able to format my code please? The iPad is borked!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use $.extend({f1: function(){},f2: function(){}}) if you wish to add more than 1 plugins together. this will make ur code look cleaner too.